# How to expand Minecraft village from single villager in survival

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In my world there is a village that has a well, a forge, and a single blacksmith. How would I go about expanding this in survival?

Comment: You'll have to cure a zombie villager. Create a splash potion of weakness, a golden apple, and create a simple trap (a 2-deep hole in the ground with a trapdoor, for example). Wait til night and move around to spawn mobs. When you find a zombie villager, lead him to the trap, make him fall in, and place a block over his head so he doesn't burn in the sun. Hit him with the potion, feed him the apple, wait 5 min, and voila. Now he can breed with your blacksmith.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credit to Dan for the answer (above). Not sure why he left it as a comment.

> You'll have to cure a zombie villager. Create a splash potion of weakness, a golden apple, and create a simple trap (a 2-deep hole in the ground with a trapdoor, for example). Wait til night and move around to spawn mobs. When you find a zombie villager, lead him to the trap, make him fall in, and place a block over his head so he doesn't burn in the sun. Hit him with the potion, feed him the apple, wait 5 min, and voila. Now he can breed with your blacksmith.